# How can I get analytics on a site without a frontend?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, api, heroku, rails-api

For example, google Analytics would require me to insert a script in my layout. However, my app has no views and is only serving an API, without an interface. Are there any services to track traffic of a JSON API ? I intend to host on heroku.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most analytics services offer some sort of server-to-server rather than client reporting of events. You should get some more consistency in data reported (e.g. you're not blocked by ad blockers or slow connections failing to load client side libraries) but also lose visibility into some events (user tracking depends on your authentication/cookie policy, time on page may be impossible to measure).

For a Rails app I'd look at https://segment.com/docs/sources/server/ruby/ which in my experience has done a good job of making it easy to report events and allows you to then forward them to whatever analytics service works best for your product.

Comment: Seems sufficient. Appreciated

Comment: In the interest of sharing. I found Mixpanel which reports events and tracks analytics itself thus eliminating the need to forward to another service.